# How to set default Save as type option to xlsx while using radgrid ExportToExcel()

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a radgrid, whose data i am exporting to excel (xls) format using radGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel(), export is working as expected, but when I open the exported xls file and click "Save as", the "Save as type:" is set to "Web Page(*.htm*.html)", it is expected to be "Excel Workbook(*.xlsx)". The export code is as below,

```
        radGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = "Export";
        radGrid.ExportSettings.HideStructureColumns = true;
        radGrid.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
        radGrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
        radGrid.MasterTableView.GroupsDefaultExpanded = true;
        radGrid.MasterTableView.Caption = string.Empty;
        radGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
```

[This is the save as type being selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLvBQ.png) - Web Page(*.htm*.html)

Please suggest.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try setting the desired format as well through `radGrid.ExportSettings.Excel.Format`
2. Compare your setup with the demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/exporting/excel-export/defaultcs.aspx
3. Try clearing the response before export

radGrid.Page.Response.ClearHeaders();
radGrid.Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
radGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();